# Why does test MSE always decrease with increasing training size (and decreasing test size)?

Tags: random-forest, lasso, ridge-regression, mse, bagging

Context:
I am trying to find the best predictive model for a dataset with 1000 observations. The problem is  I am not sure what the best training and test size should be. So what I did was that I ran a loop to vary the training size from 1 to 999 (and the rest as test set, size from 999 to 1) for my predictive models and find the one with the lowest MSE.

Problem:
It seems that for Ridge Regression, Lasso Regression, Bagging and Random Forest procedures, the models that gives the lowest MSE for each method all have training size close to 999. The plot of training size against MSE can be seen below (I omitted the first 900 since their MSE is way too high, but generally there is a downward trend in MSE as training size increase). Why is this the case?

[image: Ridge]

[image: Lasso]

[image: Bagging]

[image: Random Forest]

Comment: "there is a downward trend in MSE as training size increase...Why is this the case?" Are you asking why more data helps to fit a model to the data's distribution better?

Comment: My bad, i actually meant the test MSE seems to decrease as training size increase. Does that mean that the predictive capability of a model is always better when we use all observations as training data? (And in which case if we want a good predictive model, we should use all observations to make our model if possible)

Comment: For clarifcation, in the above if training size = 900, test size =100. MSE is calculated by sum of the (predicted response of test set using the training model - actual y values in test set)^2

Answer (score 1):

As the training set increases, the estimation precision improves, and the expected value of the squared error goes down.*,** As the test set gets smaller simultaneously, the variance of the test error increases. This is what you see in all of the pictures.

*The mean squared error is an estimate of that, and it goes down *on average* across the possible samples from the population or the data generating process, though it may not do that in some particular samples.
**Thus regarding *Does that mean that the predictive capability of a model is always better when we use all observations as training data? (And in which case if we want a good predictive model, we should use all observations to make our model if possible)* - Generally yes.

Answer (score 0):

To my eye, what you have is more a problem with high variance in RMSE evaluated on the remaining test samples rather than a low RMSE *per se* when you have a high fraction of cases in the training set. For example, in the second-from-the-bottom plot, the last RMSE is one of the *highest* that you show. All the plots seem to show higher noise once you get beyond a training set of about 970.

This is what you might well expect: if you only have a few dozen cases to test your model on, the performance is likely to be very dependent on the particular train/test split that you performed. In the limit of 999 in your training set you are using leave-one-out cross validation, which typically has high variance. See [An Introduction to Statistical Learning, second edition](https://www.statlearning.com/), Section 5.1.4.

This is why Frank Harrell, for example, recommends that you don't use train/test splits unless you have [on the order of 20,000 cases](https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/). Building a model on all the data followed by bootstrap resampling to validate the model-building process is generally preferable for samples of this size. If you insist on cross-validation, do multiple repeated cross-validations of the model-building process at more typical 5- or 10-fold CV.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is the fundamental property of all machine learning algorithms to improve performance with more available training data. It has been coined by Mitchell in 1997:

> "A computer program is said to learn from experience E with respect to
> some class of tasks T and performance measure P if its performance at
> tasks in T, as measured by P, improves with experience E." Tom Mitchell